# Why does gog.com not load properly in chromedriver

Tags: html, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

The image below shows how gog.com appears on google chrome (left), and then on chromedriver (right). why does it not load properly on chromedriver?

[image: screenshot]

Everything seems massively out of proportion and broken in chromedriver. Also I could find no difference in the 2 htmls which wasn't due to the price or name of a game (which is randomly chosen anyway).

My script for chromedriver is literally just:

```
driver_xpath2 = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_xpath2)
driver.get("https://www.gog.com/")
```

1. why does chromedriver create this different looking page than chrome?
2. i keep reading that it is impossible to detect that someone is using chromedriver rather than just chrome. is it really? (aside from monitoring for computerishly routine events and patterns in user behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use the latest chrome driver version [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

If you're already using the latest version, to work around the issue I suggest using the Chrome Profile you're using on the left screenshot.

To load it just use:

```
service = Service('path\\to\\chromedriver.exe') # your driver path

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument \
    (r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\your_user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") # your chrome user data directory
chrome_options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default') # the profile you need
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
```

The code above also add the chrome driver `.exe` in a more elegant way